# Import android Eclipse project into android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I get the following error when trying to import my project into Android Studio. I have tried to update everything in eclipse before exporting and also in android studio (2.10). I can create a new android project, just have not been able to import it! any pointers in the right direction would be helpful. Also, I'm not that familiar with the Android studio IDE log and have not been able to get any useful information from it.

Thanks!

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct this problem I started with a fresh instal of both Android Studio and and Eclipse. I was then able to export and then import the project.